# How to store a computed field declared in old API in Odoo v8?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have to store an existing computed field in Odoo 8 (only because it should be sortable for the users). The field is `debit`, which you can find in the module *analytic*, file *analytic.py*, model `account.analytic.account`.

The problem is, unfortunately, the field is declared in old API, and I am trying to store it using that one. By the way, adding only `store=True` to the field does not work (every record debit is 0 after that, even if I remove the column `debit` from the database once is stored and update my module to regenerate it), so I have to use the "old" `@api.depends`.

The model `account.analytic.account`, has a One2many field named `line_ids` which points to `account.analytic.line`. The field `debit` depends on this field, `line_ids`, and the fields `account_id`, `date` and `amount` of the `account.analytic.line` model. So in new API, the compute method should have this decorator above:

```
@api.depends('line_ids', 'line_ids.account_id', 'line_ids.date', 'line_ids.amount')
```

But I have to tell that in old API, so I did what I knew about that.

My code:

```
def _get_analytic_account_to_update_from_analytic_line(self, cr, uid, line_ids,
                                                       context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    lines = self.browse(cr, uid, line_ids, context=context)
    analytic_ids = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.account_id and line.account_id.id not in analytic_ids:
            analytic_ids.append(line.account_id.id)
    return analytic_ids

_columns = {
    'debit': osv_fields.function(
        _debit_credit_bal_qtty,
        type='float',
        string='Debit',
        multi='debit_credit_bal_qtty',
        digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'),
        store={
            'account.analytic.line': (
                _get_analytic_account_to_update_from_analytic_line,
                ['account_id', 'date', 'amount'],
                10
            )
        },
    ),
}
```

But there must be a mistake because every record debit is 0 (like if I put `store=True`). However, if I put `store=False`, every record debit is rightly computed.

The workflow is not even going into my method `_get_analytic_account_to_update_from_analytic_line` when the values should be computed.

Does anyone remember anything about this old API `store` dictionary? Any advice?

Would you migrate the whole compute method to new API only to make it being stored in the database?

Comment: You should get an error with this code, because `_debit_credit_bal_qtty()` is nowhere defined. Is there more code? Yes i know, it's defined in the origin class, but you call it directly without import or redefinition (super).

Comment: @CZoellner, yes, I did not paste the whole code. What you do not see here is that I did a `super` to call the original method. I guess it would be better to import the method, though.

Comment: Hm, i don't see a mistake in that code snippet. I have no idea, why `store=True` and `store=False` is providing different values.